# *R* do.call() and eval(call()) function error

Tags: r, function, mean

```
age=c(30,30,37,35,33)
call("mean", age)
eval(call("mean",age))  # 33
age2<-as.list(age) # since it sould be list for do.call
do.call("mean",age2) # 30
```

why `do.call()` and `eval(call())` give me different mean value while they use a same function with same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```
age2 <- as.list(age) # since it sould be list for do.call
do.call("mean",age2)
```

that's the same as

```
mean(30,30,37,35,33)
```

which is not the same as

```
mean(c(30,30,37,35,33))
```

what you want is just `list()`, not `as.list()`

```
age2 <- list(age) # since it sould be list for do.call
do.call("mean", age2)
```

The list should be a list of parameters. The one parameter you are passing to `mean` should be a vector of values. You want `length(age2)` to be 1 in this case.